# Turn ASP.NET's "ReturnURL" into absolute URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, forms-authentication

I have two secure sites:

```
siteA.example.com
siteB.example.com
```

A common sign in page exists on siteA.example.com.  If you visit siteB.example.com without logging in, you are redirected to siteA.example.com.  The URL ends up looking like this:

http://siteA.example.com/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2f

This doesn't work for me, because the return URL actually just ends up taking you to the homepage of siteA.example.com even though the user visited siteB.example.com.

Is there a configurable way to fix this?  Or should I just hook into one of the global life cycle events to change the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a [custom module](http://blogs.freshlogicstudios.com/Posts/View.aspx?Id=cb739183-6a0b-46bc-9179-22aed8e60433) or use a [custom authorize attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379506/forms-authentication-asp-net-mvc-absolute-returnurl).

Comment: I get the infamous Darin to respond to one of my posts?  :)  Thanks for the link.  I figured a module or event would likely be my solution, but I wanted to make sure I didn't overlook something with forms authentication.  Also, cheers for the help you've provided on StackOverflow.  My last few months of learning and working with MVC were finding your posts quite often.

Comment: Too bad the content isn't posted, the link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

I found this little trick :

change your config for

```
 <forms loginUrl="http://google.com/Login?domain=http://google.fr/" />
```

Where google.com is where you'll enter your credentials and google.fr is the app needing a logged in user.

Then you'll just have to concatene this with the parameter ReturnUrl before redirecting the user.

Comment: So simple I wish I'd thought of it. You need custom login handler logic, but my particular situation requires that anyway (mixed-mode authentication).

Answer (score 0):

When setting the value for returnURL use UrlHelper. Use the overload that allows you to set the host name, and pass in sizeA.example.com.

```
UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null, "action", "controller", "http", "siteA.example.com", null, new { id = "Awesome" }, routes);
```