# MVC3 Account Login auto-appending ReturnUrl

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a .NET MVC3 app that is set to authenticate using the built in role provider.  The thing is, I have the authentication app broken out into a separate app and am using that as a Single Sign-On system.

Everything is working, my only issue is that I'm hard-coding a return URL into the web.config, like:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="http://localhost:59179/Account/LogOn/?ReturnUrl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A64361%2F" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

This works, the issue is that a second returlUrl parameter is being appended to the end of the query string, and that is breaking the 1st returnUrl.

Is there a way that I can prevent this 2nd &returnUrl from being auto-appended to the end?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that ReturnUrl is appended by AuthorizeAttribute. You could derive your own AuthorizeAttribute and then add any ReturnUrl you wanted (or none at all).

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379506/forms-authentication-asp-net-mvc-absolute-returnurl) an answer on how to manually append a return url in an authorize filter.