# Redirecting a user after successful login

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know after session has expired . I can redirect a user to login page.

Is there a way I can redirect a user after successful login to the page it was viewing before the session expired?

eg. User 'U' viewing the page 'BeforeSessionExpired' session expired redirected to 'LoginPage'

Successful logging redirect to 'BeforeSessionExpired'.

I am using `ASP.Net MVC` with `Form Authentication`.

Comment: that URL is stored into 'returnUrl' string. which you can use to Redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if following lines exist in your web.config file

```
<appSettings>
   ...
   <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
</appSettings>

...

<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="43200" /> <!--43,200 in minutes - 30 days-->
</authentication>
```

or either add the following lines to the AppSettings section of my web.config file

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

or In your Logon View, are you passing the url to the Post method?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", new { returnUrl= Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }))
 { 
   <input type="submit" value="Login" />
 }
```

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146032/redirect-to-requested-page-after-authentication

Comment: Could you please elaborate new { returnUrl= Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }))

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", new { returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }, FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes:null))
 { 
   <input type="submit" value="Login" />
 }

Comment: When using forms authentication and the user is not authenticated or authorized the ASP.NET security pipeline will redirect to the login page and pass as a parameter in the query string the returnUrl equal to the page that redirected to the login page.

Comment: How about ajax request? Say I requested a partial page through ajax request and session expired. Will this approach still work in case of ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `Login` controller with `Index` method for rendering login page.  Also suppose, you have a controller `Account` with action `Index` that renders your hypothetical BeforeSessionExpired page.

In `Account/Index` action

```
if not ((System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User != null) and System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)  then
   Session("LastURL") = "Account"
   RedirectToAction("Login","Index")
end if
```

In `Login/Index` action

After successful login

```
if not string.IsNullorWhiteSpace(Session("LastURL"))then

    RedirectToAction(Session("LastURL"),"Index")
end if
```

Of course this is just exemplary code, you can modify the code according to your needs.