# Redirecting user after completed ActionMethod in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In one of my Controllers i have this "Edit" Action Method where registered user can edit his personal information (Name, Phone Number etc.), this Action Method can be called from two different places (from two different Controllers and two different Action Methods) on my website, i want to implement following:

-if "Edit" Action Method is called from "place A", then after this Action Method is completed redirect user to "View A"

-if "Edit" Action Method is called from "place B", then after this Action Method is completed redirect user to "View B"

I don't have any idea how to do this, so please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect to requested page after authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146032/redirect-to-requested-page-after-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

You can use place name as action parameter

```
public ActionResult Edit(User user, string viewName)
{
    **Your code**
    ..
    ..
    ..
    if(viewName == "place A") return View("View A");
    else if(viewName == "place b") return View("View b");
}
```

or use `switch case`