# Redirect to a specific view in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm sending by email info about my web admin, there is a link whit my controller/view, so when a user click that link the system should to go to login page (I have a page to do it).

If the login is ok I want to go the specific controller / view / parameter. By default the web admin goes to index page when the login is ok but I don't know how to define to go another view.

[AllowAnonymous]
public JsonResult Login(string usuario, string contrasena) {

```
        Response respuesta = new Response();
        LoginVM _usuarioResponse = new LoginVM();
        try
        {
           mensaje = //login in database methid here
            if (mensaje == "ok")
            {
                ..
                ..
                ..
                respuesta.status = Status.Success;
                respuesta.message = mensaje;
                respuesta.result = Url.Action("Index","Home");
                
            }
            else
            {
                respuesta.status = Status.Error;
                respuesta.message = mensaje;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            respuesta.status = Status.Error;
            respuesta.message = ex.Message;
            respuesta.result = ex.ToString();
        }
        return Json(respuesta, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Im returning a url whit the main page after login, i want to go to another view after login when the user click on the email link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect to requested page after authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146032/redirect-to-requested-page-after-authentication)

Comment: Link to the actual view. If your website is setup correctly (See duplicate), the visitor is first asked to login and then returned to the view you link to.

Comment: I just edited the question, put my code there

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using the `RedirectToAction` method:

```
if (loginSuccessful)
{
  return RedirectToAction("SpecificView", new { param1 = value1, param2 = value2 });
}
```